# Modifying a React template to call an API instead of hard coded data

Tags: reactjs

New to learning React.  Completed a few tutorials on calling API's using Axios which is working fine for API calls.  However I am now trying to incorporate what I have learned into a React template.  The template in question is the [Shards Dashboard Lite React](https://designrevision.com/downloads/shards-dashboard-lite-react/).

I have the complete BlogOverview.js file below.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "shards-react";

import PageTitle from "./../components/common/PageTitle";
import SmallStats from "./../components/common/SmallStats";
import PendantUsage from "./../components/blog/PendantUsage";
import UsersByDevice from "./../components/blog/UsersByDevice";
import NewDraft from "./../components/blog/NewDraft";
import Discussions from "./../components/blog/Discussions";
import TopReferrals from "./../components/common/TopReferrals";

const BlogOverview = ({ smallStats }) => (
  <Container fluid className="main-content-container px-4">
    {/* Page Header */}
    <Row noGutters className="page-header py-4">
      <PageTitle
        title="Blog Overview"
        subtitle="Dashboard"
        className="text-sm-left mb-3"
      />
    </Row>

    {/* Small Stats Blocks */}
    <Row>
      {smallStats.map((stats, idx) => (
        <Col className="col-lg mb-4" key={idx} {...stats.attrs}>
          <SmallStats
            id={`small-stats-${idx}`}
            variation="1"
            chartData={stats.datasets}
            chartLabels={stats.chartLabels}
            label={stats.label}
            value={stats.value}
            percentage={stats.percentage}
            increase={stats.increase}
            decrease={stats.decrease}
          />
        </Col>
      ))}
    </Row>

    <Row>
      {/* Users Overview */}
      <Col lg="8" md="12" sm="12" className="mb-4">
        <PendantUsage />
      </Col>

      {/* Users by Device */}
      <Col lg="4" md="6" sm="12" className="mb-4">
        <UsersByDevice />
      </Col>

      {/* New Draft */}
      <Col lg="4" md="6" sm="12" className="mb-4">
        <NewDraft />
      </Col>

      {/* Discussions */}
      <Col lg="5" md="12" sm="12" className="mb-4">
        <Discussions />
      </Col>

      {/* Top Referrals */}
      <Col lg="3" md="12" sm="12" className="mb-4">
        <TopReferrals />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
);

BlogOverview.propTypes = {
  /**
   * The small stats dataset.
   */
  smallStats: PropTypes.array
};

BlogOverview.defaultProps = {
  smallStats: [
    {
      label: "Battery Level",
      value: "98%",
      percentage: "4.7%",
      increase: true,
      chartLabels: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      attrs: { md: "6", sm: "6" },
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Today",
          fill: "start",
          borderWidth: 1.5,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 184, 216, 0.1)",
          borderColor: "rgb(0, 184, 216)",
          data: [1, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 7]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Last Event",
      value: "14th Dec",
      percentage: "4.7%",
      increase: true,
      chartLabels: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      attrs: { md: "6", sm: "6" },
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Today",
          fill: "start",
          borderWidth: 1.5,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 184, 216, 0.1)",
          borderColor: "rgb(0, 184, 216)",
          data: [1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 7]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Pages",
      value: "182",
      percentage: "12.4",
      increase: true,
      chartLabels: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      attrs: { md: "6", sm: "6" },
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Today",
          fill: "start",
          borderWidth: 1.5,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(23,198,113,0.1)",
          borderColor: "rgb(23,198,113)",
          data: [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Comments",
      value: "8,147",
      percentage: "3.8%",
      increase: false,
      decrease: true,
      chartLabels: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      attrs: { md: "4", sm: "6" },
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Today",
          fill: "start",
          borderWidth: 1.5,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,180,0,0.1)",
          borderColor: "rgb(255,180,0)",
          data: [2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "New Customers",
      value: "29",
      percentage: "2.71%",
      increase: false,
      decrease: true,
      chartLabels: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      attrs: { md: "4", sm: "6" },
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Today",
          fill: "start",
          borderWidth: 1.5,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,65,105,0.1)",
          borderColor: "rgb(255,65,105)",
          data: [1, 7, 1, 3, 1, 4, 8]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Subscribers",
      value: "17,281",
      percentage: "2.4%",
      increase: false,
      decrease: true,
      chartLabels: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      attrs: { md: "4", sm: "6" },
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Today",
          fill: "start",
          borderWidth: 1.5,
          backgroundColor: "rgb(0,123,255,0.1)",
          borderColor: "rgb(0,123,255)",
          data: [3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

export default BlogOverview;
```

In the first instance all I want to do is get to grips with how I can turn the hard coded smallStats data into data returned from an API.  For example the first item has a hard coded battery level of (value) 98%.  I want to substitute this for a return value from my API.

Some of the things I have tried are including a function to do an async api call and then call the function from the defaultprops value attribute.  I've read that you should do API calls from the componentDidMount event.  So I tried that from the SmallStats component itself but then I could not change state as it only has props.

In all, I'm getting quite confused.  Any pointers into how I can get past this hurdle?  Hoping that once I've proven the integration of one API instead of using the default hard coded data I should be on my way...

Answer (score 0):

Long story short.   Think this is all down to me not understanding React in enough detail.  Ended up changing the stateless functional component into a class and introducing state so that I could manipulate it with API responses in the ComponentDidMount method.